# R: :Error in forecast (fit, h = 6) : unused argument (h = 6)

Tags: r, time-series, arima, forecast

i'm tring to do a forecast on univariate time series using R.

I use forecast package. I used first auto.arima and then i saved output of the function in variable fit.

Then i used the function forecast(fit, h=6) because i would forecast the next 6 mounth.

I have this type of error:
Error in forecast(fit, h = 6) : unused argument (h = 6)

Anyone know what was wrong? I read a lot of examples that use this procedure.

Thanks

Comment: Most likely you've loaded another package that is masking the forecast() function from the forecast package.

Comment: Try specifying the package in the function call and see if that solves the problem: `forecast:: forecast(fit, h=6)`

Answer (score 2):

Recheck the library you've loaded, I faced this error because I loaded TSA and aTSA library simultaneously.